# How can SML infer types like this?

Tags: compilers, functional-programming, type-theory, type-inference

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML):

```
fun factorial n = 
    if n = 0 then 1 else n * factorial (n-1)
```

> A Standard ML compiler is required to infer the static type int -> int of this function
>   without user-supplied type annotations. I.e., it has to deduce that n
>   is only used with integer expressions, and must therefore itself be an
>   integer, and that all value-producing expressions within the function
>   return integers.

I don't understand how a compiler could infer this. It sounds like SML is essentially solving the halting problem for the `factorial` function, and showing that it only halts on positive integer inputs.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm requires each literal value to be unambiguously inferable to a type: `0` is an `int`, while `0.0` is a `real`. Haskell's type system has been enhanced to include a certain kind of bounded polymorphism, so that `0` can have any type that is a number (more precisely, of any type that is an instance of the `Num` type class: `0` is of type `Num a => a`).

See the [wikipedia article on Hindley-Milner](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner) for further details on the algorithm (the article explanations are much better than anything I could write on that topic).

Comment: thinking about it, I wonder if I actually answer your question.

Comment: `if ... then ... else ... ` is more accurately seen as an expression that should take three (sub)expressions, one having bool type and the other two having matching but otherwise unrestricted types. Otherwise, yeah, I think you gave a sufficient answer.

Comment: I agree, I tried to turn the `if` expression in a function, to avoid adding a special case to handle in the algorithm. That might be not necessary for the purpose of this answer, so you have a point.

Comment: My question is: how does SML know the function isn't of type `Real -> Real`? Since 0 and 1 are both real numbers, it can't just look at the constants' types.

Comment: Now I understand better your question!

Comment: Ah OK. If the Real version of `0` is required to be written as `0.0`, this makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Xodarap: In ML when you write [0 it's not a real, you have to write 0.0 to get a real](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Standard_ML_Programming/Types#Basic_types). So the ML compiler is not confused in any way about the type of 0, i.e. it's uniquely determined in ML. After that it's all Hindley-Milner type inference in ML, which is decidable.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is important to realise what the type $\mathtt{int \rightarrow int}$ means and does not mean.

It
does *not* mean that a program P having that type must return an
integer, contrary to what the original poster said. Instead it means
**if P terminates on a given input (of type int), P terminates by returning an integer.** 
This way the halting problem is not an issue.

In addition, well-typing guarantees that  programs don't suffer run-time type errors even when not terminating.

The original Milner, Damas paper [Principal
type-schemes for functional programs](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~crary/819-f09/DamasMilner82.pdf) is very readable.  With 6 pages it's also short.

Finally, it is highly instructive, and not much effort, to implement a
type-inferencer for a toy language. I recommend doing this to really understand
how types work in programming languages.

Comment: Then why doesn't the type read `Real -> Real`? Surely the equivalent statement is true: "If P terminates on an input of type Real, P terminates by returning a Real"

Comment: @Xodarap that's because subterms like 0 and 1 are not of type `real`. SML has no subtyping (IIRC).

Comment: @Xodarap, generally speaking, it depends on the type system of the language. Some other languages' type systems might do just that: subsume $int$ to $real$ if necessary to do that, but it would require a type system that recognizes that $int$s are $real$s, which generally implies that the language supports subtyping.

Answer (score 4):

Working with types is not as "hard" as working with values with respect to computability. You can know statically that a function will return a `bool` without knowing statically that it will return `true`, for example. Moreover, it's entirely possible and sometimes trivially easy to prove that a *specific given* function halts with a certain input, but this is a different problem than writing a general algorithm that determines whether or not *any* other given function will halt on an input.

With respect to how type inference works, let me recommend some sources which may help:

1. [Unification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_%28computer_science%29) on Wikipedia
2. [Type inference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) on Wikipedia
3. [Types and Programming Languages](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/) by Benjamin C. Pierce (chapter 22, especially)
4. [Hindley-Milner method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner) on Wikipedia.

The type inference algorithm happens essentially in two phases: constraint generation, and unification. During constraint generation, the AST of the program is traversed and a set of type constraints is generated.

For example, if somewhere in the program there is the application expression `myfun (3)`, the inference algorithm could infer that the type of `myfun` is $\tt{int} \rightarrow \alpha$. If in another part of the program the expression `4 + myfun(y)` is encountered, the constraint that `myfun` has type $\beta \rightarrow \tt{int}$ is generated. During the unification step, such constraints will be (successfully or unsuccessfully) unified. During this phase the set of constraints might include

- $ \tt{myfun} : \tt{int} \rightarrow \alpha$
- $ \tt{myfun} : \beta \rightarrow \tt{int}$
- $ \tt{y} : \tt{int}$
- $ \tt{y} : \beta$

From this set (really system) of constraints, we could infer that $\alpha = \tt{int}$ and $\beta = \tt{int}$, and everything would be consistent and the program would type check. It's possible for unification to fail, though, depending on what else is in the set of constraints.

Comment: The sample code has the following feature: no type errors will be generated if it is called with say `1.5`, as you can compare 1.5 to 1 easily. However, the function will fail to terminate if it is called with 1.5. How does SML know this?

Comment: @Xodarap, in your sample code, SML doesn't infer that the type is `int` because it is what will make calls to `factorial` terminate; it infers that because you used the constant value expression `1` instead of `1.0`.